# Masonry images not working

Tags: plugins, themes, troubleshooting, masonry

Until yesterday, all 10 tiles were showing on the main page on [this website](https://crossroads-demo.threadsoftware.net/cc/).

After updating 3-4 pages and adding a "blog" function to them (separated by category), only 3-6 tiles will show at any given time.

The theme is Waxom and I am using WP bakery. The tiles link to portfolio items. I've tried changing the order, the max amount of tiles. I've tried filtering through categories and using pages instead.

I'm at a loss of what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.